# Login as an admin in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, crud

I made authentication in laravel  with --auth and register/login was done  automatically. Now I want to add a part for my app to  login as an admin and and if I am an admin to have acces at CRUD and if I am just an user to do not have acces at CRUD and I want to know what I have to do for that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear enough ...
but you can

1-add is_admin field to your user table to determine which user in admin.

2-when ever you want to hide something from user who is not admin, you can check the user like this:

```
if(auth()->user()->is_admin == 1)
  //its admin-can do crud
else
  //it is not and cant do crud
```